# Want to flip side portion of UIView like given example of image

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, flip

[image]

I am looking for same animation like given in image, had try a lot but could not find that how to curl one side portion of UIView. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What did you try, and did it include a `CATransform3D`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally done that animation with help of MPFlipVIew here is like if anybody want same : https://github.com/mpospese/MPFlipViewController